# What is the proper way to know the size of DB needed for SonarQube?

Tags: database, sonarqube, size, code-analysis, sonarqube-ops

From what I have seen on the web they say:

> 2.The amount of disk space you need will depend on how much code you analyze with SonarQube. As an example, SonarCloud the public instance of SonarQube, has more than 30 millions lines of code under analysis with 4 years of history. SonarCloud is currently running on a Amazon EC2 m4.large instance, using about 10 Gb of drive space. It handles 800+ projects having roughly 3M open issues. SonarCloud is running on PostgreSQL 9.5 and it is using about 15Gb of drive space.

However it is not very clear. Do I just need to count the amount of lines of code we have and then do a rough estimate or what would be the best way to know the size of the DB we need?

Thank you for your help!
I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Why not analyse one or two typical projects for some time and extrapolate that?

Comment: Thank you for your proposition, I never tought about that :)